# How do we generate the ROC curve for Linear Discriminant Analysis method

Tags: classification, generalized-linear-model, roc, discriminant-analysis

I know the method to generate the ROC curve for other methods such as naive Bayes where the tuning parameter is the threshold like also in logistic regression.

If we want to generate the ROC curve for linear discriminant analysis method used in binary classification what is the tuning parameter here?

Comment: In case of binary classification, LDA projects the data onto one discriminant axis and sets a threshold on this axis to classify into one group or another. One can view this threshold as a tuning parameter.

Comment: ROC curves generation only takes two imputes. The true binary observations and the predicted values. It sorts them based on the predicted values. And for each value of the predicted values it separates the true observation into two groups and plots the correct positives vs the false positives.  No matter what method you use. If it gives real predicted values you can always generate a ROC curve.

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha: but what is "predicted value" in LDA?

Comment: @amoeba Yes I was about to ask that as well. I read that the classification happens based on this condition b(u− x1)−b(u− x2)<0 where b is the set of coeff and u is the given sample with x1 and x2 the means of the classes.

Comment: How will you be using the results of the analysis?  What about the problem leads you to think that ROC curves are more useful that LDA's posterior probabilities?  Why did you chose the more assumption-laden LDA approach over logistic regression?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Actually i have been learning ML. So I learned about ROC and wondering how is it generated for LDA

Comment: @amoeba: the decision boundary of the LDA is of the form $\omega.x$, where $x$ are the predictors. Normally you will say when $\omega .x>0$ predict 1 and 0 otherwise. Use the $\omega. x$ as your predicted values. So the ROC is generated from different cut-offs not just 0.

Comment: The ROC does not play a role here.  ROC is mainly a way to avoid thinking about utilities/cost/loss functions and invites arbitrary thresholding.