# How to find correlation if we have continuous and categorical variables present in my dataset as features and target is again binary

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, feature-selection

I am working on classification problem where I have categorical and continuous features however the target is binary.

1. What is the best way to check correlation with respect to target variable.
2. Also I want to eliminate some features which are highly correlated.

I have generated a correlation heatmap for continuous features and for categorical features I am thinking to perform a chi square test .

Is this a right approach? Do I have to apply two different methods for continuous and  categorical features?

Comment: Related: [Correlations with unordered categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/108007/7290).

Answer (score 1):

For correlations between continuous and categorical variables see [Correlations between continuous and categorical (nominal) variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables) and [Correlations with unordered categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-unordered-categorical-variables).

But your main question seems to be about classification into two classes, since the target is binary. It is in most cases better to see this as a risk estimation problem, and that can be modeled via **logistic regression**, see [Choosing between logistic and discriminant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192030/choosing-between-logistic-and-discriminant),   [Why isn't Logistic Regression called Logistic Classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification/127044#127044),   [When is logistic regression suitable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198067/when-is-logistic-regression-suitable/198187#198187)

And finally, you want to eliminate features. Doing that by bivariate correlation/association is seldom a good idea. See [How to reduce predictors the right way for a logistic regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398638/how-to-reduce-predictors-the-right-way-for-a-logistic-regression-model).